# Can I get all rows for numeric columns in data.table with setkey()?

Tags: r, data.table

if I use setkey on character column data.table returns all row with e.g.

```
DT <- data.table(V1=c(1L,2L),
V2=LETTERS[1:3],
V3=round(rnorm(4),4),
V4=1:12)

setkey(DT,V2)

DT['A'] = 
   V1 V2      V3 V4
1:  1  A  0.6741  1
2:  2  A  0.5648  4
3:  1  A -1.0006  7
4:  2  A  0.5047 10
```

but that does not work with numeric column e.g.

```
DT <- data.table(V1=c(1L,2L),
    V2=LETTERS[1:3],
    V3=round(rnorm(4),4),
    V4=1:12)
setkey(DT,V1)
1:  1  C -1.3419  3
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `J(1)` or `.(1)`, like this:

```
DT[.(1)]
#    V1 V2      V3 V4
# 1:  1  A -0.0780  1
# 2:  1  C  1.0128  3
# 3:  1  B -0.0780  5
# 4:  1  A  1.0128  7
# 5:  1  C -0.0780  9
# 6:  1  B  1.0128 11
DT[J(1)]
#    V1 V2      V3 V4
# 1:  1  A -0.0780  1
# 2:  1  C  1.0128  3
# 3:  1  B -0.0780  5
# 4:  1  A  1.0128  7
# 5:  1  C -0.0780  9
# 6:  1  B  1.0128 11
```